# Why does taking `istream&` to a temporary `stringstream` work, but not when taking `stringstream&`?

Tags: c++, rvalue

Consider the following code, it compiles and runs:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
struct Foo {};
void operator>>(std::istream &, Foo) {
}
int main() {
    std::stringstream{} >> Foo{};
}
```

However, if I change `std::istream` to `std::stringstream`, I get an error:

```
c.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c.cpp:7:25: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'} and 'Foo')
    7 |     std::stringstream{} >> Foo{};
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~
      |          |                 |
      |          |                 Foo
      |          std::stringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>}
c.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: 'void operator>>(std::stringstream&, Foo)' (near match)
    4 | void operator>>(std::stringstream &, Foo) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~
c.cpp:4:6: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
c.cpp:7:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::stringstream&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>&'} to an rvalue of type 'std::stringstream' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>'}
    7 |     std::stringstream{} >> Foo{};
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

which makes sense: I cannot bind a lvalue reference to a rvalue (temporary) object.

Why does the first code compile?

**UPD**: my compiler is

```
g++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and flags are `-std=gnu++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -O2`

**UPD2**: at the very end there is an error regarding the operator which Brian Bi is talking about:

```
In file included from C:/Software/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/iostream:40,
                 from c.cpp:1:
C:/Software/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/istream:980:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Istream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Istream>, std::__is_extractable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type, _Tp&&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type>::type std::operator>>(_Istream&&, _Tp&&)'
  980 |     operator>>(_Istream&& __is, _Tp&& __x)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Software/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/istream:980:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/Software/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/istream: In substitution of 'template<class _Istream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Istream>, std::__is_extractable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type, _Tp&&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_istream<_Tp>::__istream_type>::type std::operator>>(_Istream&&, _Tp&&) [with _Istream = std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>; _Tp = Foo]':
c.cpp:7:32:   required from here
C:/Software/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/istream:980:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_istream<char>&>'
```

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: [I can reproduce](https://ideone.com/86pfaY). I have no explanation for why it works.

Comment: Both versions compile (see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/os1c74sb6)) on gcc 11.2 and clang trunk. `stringstring` version fails to compile on older versions.

Comment: * `stringstream`, obviously.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As strange as it might seem, this code is well-formed. It should always compile. See [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4hs4ME4vf). It should also compile when the `operator>>` overload is changed to take `std::stringstream&`.

The reason is that there exists a special rvalue `operator>>` overload for classes derived from `std::ios_base`, marked (3) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2):

```
template< class Istream, class T >
Istream&& operator>>( Istream&& st, T&& value );
```

The effect is equivalent to:

```
st >> std::forward<T>(value);
return std::move(st);
```

This is the `operator>>` overload that is called by your code. It delegates to the `operator>>` that you've written. (Because `Foo` is a member of the global namespace, unqualified name lookup will find your `operator>>` from any context thanks to ADL.)

If you have a toolchain that doesn't have the rvalue stream extraction operator, then your code will not compile because, obviously, a non-const lvalue reference, `Base&`, will never bind to an rvalue of type `Derived` (where `Derived` is derived from `Base`).

I don't know exactly why the rvalue stream extraction operator exists in the standard library. I *think* it's because someone realized that there's no good reason for `is >> x` not to work if `is` happens to be an rvalue expression of stream type. But many of the existing `operator>>`s were free functions taking an lvalue reference to `basic_istream` as their first argument. So adding this rvalue `operator>>` overload, which delegates to an lvalue one, was the solution to this problem. According to this point of view, the fact that your code compiles is not a bug: it's intentional that you can write an `operator>>` that takes a non-const lvalue reference to stream type and have it work on rvalues too.

Comment: Hmm, isn't it the [LWG issue 1203](https://wg21.link/lwg1203) which only came into effect in C++20? Looks like in C++17 it was `operator>>(istream&, T&&)`, and cppreference said so before [this change](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2&diff=116602&oldid=106958). If that's the case, the code is invalid in C++17

Comment: I always found strange that the standard incorporated an unconstrained template `template< class Istream, class T > Istream&& operator>>( Istream&& st, T&& value );`. Istream can be anything (well it is only protected by ADL, but `T` can trigger ADL.

Comment: Funny I just asked about templating operator<< completely. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321711/implement-printable-class-without-paying-for-iostream-compilation?noredirect=1#comment122525033_69321711

Comment: @yeputons It seems that the specification of this operator did change slightly in C++20. However, the C++11 version should still work. The `std::basic_istream<charT, traits>&&` can still bind to an rvalue of a derived class.

Comment: @yeputons Actually, I see you mentioned a different change on cppreference where the second argument was changed from `T&` to `T&&` in C++17. So I guess the code is valid in C++17, but before C++17 the operator is not viable because of the `Foo` rvalue.

Comment: @BrianBi It can, but it looks like the implementation would be unable to call the `operator<<` as it takes `stringstream&` as an argument. However, the helping operator is not templated and has no way of remembering that it has to convert `istream&` back to `stringstream&`, doesn't it?

Comment: @yeputons Oh I see, you're right. Inside the function, it would be an `istream` so a user-defined `operator<<` that takes a `stringstream` argument can't be used. So I guess the code only becomes valid starting in C++20.