# Is there a list of all changes retroactively applied to published C++ standards?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Inspired by my [more specific question on LWG 1203](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325059/was-lwg1203-more-useful-rvalue-stream-insertion-retroactively-applied-to-c11).

I've noted that [this page](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html) lists C++ Standard Library Defect Reports (`LWGxxxx`). As I understand, if they are marked with "C++20", "C++17", etc, they are retroactively applied to already published C++ standards. There is [a similar page for Core Language Defect Reports](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html) (`CWGxxxx`).

However, some proposals, like [P2216R3](https://wg21.link/p2216r3) also got voted to become a Defect Report against C++20, as indicated in its "LEWG Polls (R1)" section. Unfortunately, it is not listed on either LWG/CWG pages and I was unable to find poll results for its more recent R3.

So I'm wondering: is there a full list of defect reports against older standards (C++20, C++17, etc)?