Does implicit lifetime object creation apply before C++20?
Several SO posts are telling that implicit-lifetime object creation has been introduced with C++20 and, indeed, I can't find mention of it in drafts for older C++.
Yet cppreference does not indicate a restriction for the langage version, except this cryptic (to me) DR at the bottom of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType:

Defect reports
The following behavior-changing defect reports were applied retroactively to previously published C++ standards.




DR
Applied to
Behavior as published
Correct behavior




CWG 2489
C++20
an operation that begins the lifetime of a char array implicitly creates objects
it does not



So does implicit lifetime object creation apply before C++20?

You said yourself that it isn't mentioned in older standards. Doesn't that answer your question?

@interjay No, because of possible retroactive application.

The DR is from the C++23 version of the standard, so it is being applied back to C++20 where this feature started.
So no, implicit lifetime types is a C++20 and above feature.

Once a standard is published, ISO doesn't go back and change the past. If you read the C++17 standard, you won't find any mention of implicit object creation.
However, standard modes older than C++20 in compilers (even compilers that are older than C++20 itself) still "support" implicit object creation in the sense that, if you try to do something that triggers implicit object creation in C++20 to make it well-defined, and you compile it in C++17 mode or earlier, the behavior will match what would have happened with implicit object creation. That's because, prior to C++20, an operation that could only be well-defined with implicit object creation would instead have undefined behaviour, but the manifestation of that undefined behaviour in all real compilers was simply to act as if the object were there, and not "exploit" the fact that an object of the required type was never created. Indeed, this was necessary so that standard libraries could implement containers like std::vector without using compiler magic.
In that sense, while implicit object creation is a C++20 feature, it has been supported by all C++ compilers forever. Though, of course, std::start_lifetime_as (which was a piece of the implicit object creation proposal that was split off into a separate paper and approved for C++23) will not exist on compilers that don't support C++20.

FWIW, they actually do go back and change previous versions, they just don't republish the standard with the correction included: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325059/was-lwg1203-more-useful-rvalue-stream-insertion-retroactively-applied-to-c11

@NathanOliver Approval of a resolution as a Defect Report merely recommends that implementations treat the new specification as retroactive to older language modes. Technically, only the most recent version of the standard is "real", and unless the Defect Reports are incorporated into a Technical Corrigendum which is approved by a vote of the national bodies, they remain mere recommendations. And there is no mechanism to correct a standard version other than the most recently published one.
